# how to loop through an array of string and turn them into ascii , while storing them in dynamic memory?

Tags: c++, loops, user-controls

> i am trying to make a program that turns each character of a string into an ascii character and store them into an array  and then print them out . However it doesn't allow me to print anything out . I have tried assigning a string to the message input and it works perfectly but it doesn't work for user input.It just ends the program and i am not receiving any errors so i don't know whats wrong with my program(c++ 11).

```
using namespace std;

string message_input{};
        int l = message_input.length();
        double* ascii_storage = new double[l +1]{};
        
        cout << "type in your message  " << endl;

        std::getline(std::cin, message_input);

        

        for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
            ascii_storage[i] = (int)message_input[i];

            cout << "the values inside the ascii baskii " << ascii_storage[i] << endl;
        }
```

Comment: All character encodings are *integer* numbers. Why do you create an array of `double`? Especially considering the (useless) C-style cast to `int` when you assign to the array?

Comment: Also, there's really no need for another array, the array stored in the string is good enough. A loop like `for (char c : message_input) { std::cout << "Character '" << c << "' has the encoded value of " << static_cast<unsigned>(c) << '\n'; }`

Comment: They're already ASCII. You're wanting the print the integer value of your (already) ASCII characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string message_input{};
```

This defines a new `std::string`. The string is empty, by default.

```
int l = message_input.length();
```

This obtains the string's `length()`. The string is empty, so `l` must be 0 at this point.

```
std::getline(std::cin, message_input);
```

This now reads some input, of unspecified length, from `std::cin`. `message_input` is now a string of some unspecified length.

The subsequent code clearly assumes that `l` gets automatically updated to the string's new length. However, C++ does not work this way, C++ does not work like a spreadsheet does. `l` is still 0, and will be 0 forever, in the shown code.

You must use `length()` or `size()` ***after*** reading the input from `std::cin`, not before.